# Thanks for having me

Tags: meaning, phrases, politeness

Is it common/correct to say "thanks for having me" after an interviewer says to you "thank you for coming to this interview"?

Thanks :)

Update: I'm referring to a job interview. (Thanks for pointing that out)

Comment: Sort of, but normally I'd go with "Thanks for taking the time to see me."

Comment: I hardly feel this is for ell ( English language and usage)..this site prefers objectivity. By the way , it depends on the situation but in general , it seems cool to me.

Comment: Or, "Thank you for interviewing me."

Comment: I hear people use it a lot, and I don't see why it would be incorrect, so I'd say yes, it's common and correct.

Comment: Interesting question to get some context... are we talking about normal interview (in which a politician, expert or other public figure answers questions that may be interesting to the target audience) or a **job interview**?

Answer (score 0):

I would say "Thank you for this interview" but more importantly, the interviewer may have seen a dozen people in a short time, and recalling your specific attributes may be lost without the post-interview thank-you note.  A handwritten, plain note-card, posted (never  emailed) is a tactile action that once again puts the focus on your candidacy.

Comment: The interviewer is not the one _giving_ the interview. So the interviewer is the one to thank _me_ for the interview, I don;t see why I should then thank the interviewer for the interview :) I also doubt how a hand written note or postcard will solve the question of what to say at the end of the interview after the interviewer thanks you :)

Comment: "An interview is a conversation between two or more people where questions are asked by the interviewer to elicit facts or statements from the interviewee"  The interview is a process initiated by the interviewer, ergo, "Thank you for this interview" acknowledges their position.   -Good God, never ever send a postcard.

Comment: The interviewee _gives_ the interview, so the _interviewer_ says thank you for the interview. Why would the interviewee, who has giving the interview to the interviewer, respond in kind, thanking someone for something they just gave them?

Comment: Are you talking about a job interview or a normal interview? Because the whole note-card and candidacy seems really really weird if I have been invited to share my views on world politics with a news-network. They probably knew my name before they called me. And they are possibly paying me for the privilege of asking me questions. They will thank me for the interview, I won't thank them for the interview I gave them. Now, if you mean a _job_ interview, things may be slightly different.

Comment: It is <i>non est disputandum</I> a confused person was addressing the "common/correct to say 'thanks for having me'".  Your reply is a carriwitchet

Comment: Then "thanks for having me" is a much better response to "Thank you for the interview" than "Thank you for the interview". Unless you had sex, in _what_ world does it make sense to thank a person for what **you** just gave to **them** and for which **they** just thanked **you**?

Comment: But indeed, it seems we _are_ talking about a _job_ interview, which, as I said before, does change things a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK "thanks for having me" would most usually be heard from a (polite) child thanking a friend's parents for a meal etc. A more appropriate phrase after a job interview might be something along the lines of "Thank you for your time", "Thank you for taking the time to see me" etc.

As an employer (again in the UK - I can't speak for elsewhere) I'd certainly recommend a follow-up letter (or maybe email if its that kind of business, NOT EVER a postcard) thanking your prospective employer and (if you can think of something appropriate) following up some point raised in the interview. It will remind them who you are and will prove you can write!